# Why am I being down voted without a solid answer?

Tags: discussion, moderator

I am getting down voted for a question that I believe is a good one, but because it has physics involved the commenters and down votes want to close it as well? Is this question not answerable here?
https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/19874/wireless-duel-field-electromagnetic-powered-space-service-drones-and-space-suits

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's really confusing. Can a wireless field control a drone? Sure, but it'd have to be an insanely powerful one. What more do you want? Also, reading the question, it isn't well formed. It's not that it has physics involved, it's that the question is poorly worded, and doesn't flow.

Try editing it, and we can see about re-opening it. But as it stands now, it's not worth keeping on the site.

Comment: I agree. The text in the question is really a jumble of ideas that are impossible to understand without a lot more explanation. However at that point it would probably not be a reasonable stackexchange question. Stackexchange is best used for fairly narrowly defined questions that are at least likely to have good, clear answers, It isn't the right place to develop entire new concepts and ideas.